# how to set a counter for parent class without child class accessing the counter in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, static, subclass, super

I have the following code where I have a `static counter field` to keep track of how many `Parent` objects are created. when I create an instance of my subclass, the counter for `parent` increases too which I dont want to happen. Any help?

here is the code

```
class Parent1 {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    public static int count=0;

    public Parent1(String name, int id){
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
        count++;
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent1{
    private int age;

    public Child1(String name, int id, int age){
        super(name, id);
        this.age=age;
    }
}
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Parent1 par= new Parent1("aa",5);
    Parent1 par2=new Parent1("bb",10);
    System.out.println(Parent1.count);
    Child1 chi1= new Child1("aa",5,4);
    Child1 chi2=new Child1("bb",5,10);
    System.out.println(Child1.count);
    }
}

The output is 
2
4
```

Comment: @paulsm4 so? that would only make the Child1.count be invalid, it would still increment it when he creates a child

Comment: @paulsm4 That wouldn't work. The superconstructor will still be called in `Child1` and the count would still be incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
class Parent1 {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    public static int count=0;

    public Parent1(String name, int id) {
        this(name, id, true);
    } 

    protected Parent1(String name, int id, boolean incrementCount){
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
        if( incrementCount )
            count++;
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent1{
    private int age;

    public Child1(String name, int id, int age){
        super(name, id, false);
        this.age=age;
    }
}

//....

Parent1 par= new Parent1("aa",5);
Parent1 par2=new Parent1("bb",10);
```

Comment: better would be both, and have all subclasses call the one you described and just use `public Parent1(String name, int id ){ this( name, id, true ); }`

Answer (score 4):

In `Parent1`'s constructor:

```
if (getClass() == Parent1.class)  // <--
    count++;
```

Comment: @Prateek Isn't it self explanatory? In the `Parent1` constructor we check to see if the class we're instantiating is specifically `Parent1`, and not a subclass.

Comment: I am not familiar with reflections hence my question

Answer (score 0):

Add `count--;` to child class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following pattern to solve the problem.

```
class Parent1 {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    public static int count=0;

    public Parent1(String name, int id){
        this(name,id,true);
        count++;
    }
    public Parent1(String name, int id,boolean noIncrement){
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent1{
    private int age;

    public Child1(String name, int id, int age){
        super(name, id,true);
        this.age=age;
    }
}
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Parent1 par= new Parent1("aa",5);
    Parent1 par2=new Parent1("bb",10);
    System.out.println(Parent1.count);
    Child1 chi1= new Child1("aa",5,4);
    Child1 chi2=new Child1("bb",5,10);
    System.out.println(Child1.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to have false in the super constructor for the child1 class.